# Return derived type from base class method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class hierarchy that looks similar to this:

```
public class Base
{
    private List<string> attributes = new List<string>();

    public T WithAttributes<T>(params string[] attributes)
        where T : Base
    {
        this.attributes.AddRange(attributes);
        return this as T;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
}
```

I want to call `Base.WithAttributes` from derived classes in a fluent-api style syntax and return the derived instance like shown in the example below.

```
void Main()
{
    Derived d = new Derived();

    // CS0411 The type arguments for method 'UserQuery.Base.WithAttributes<T>(params string[])' cannot be inferred from the usage.
    d.WithAttributes("one", "two"); 

    // Works, but type arguments must be explicity specified. 
    d.WithAttributes<Derived>("one", "two");

    // Works without explicitly specifying, but no access to private members!
    d.WithAttributesEx("one", "two");
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T WithAttributesEx<T>(this T obj, params string[] attributes)
        where T : Base
    {
        // No access to private members, argh!
        // obj.attributes.AddRange(attributes);
        return obj as T;
    }
}
```

1. Why can't the compiler infer type arguments in the first example?
2. Why does it work when called using an extension method?
3. Is there any way to make it work as an instance method on the base class without explicitly specifying type argument?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123354/259808

Comment: It doesn't work because there's no link between the `T` in `Base<T>` and the one in `WithAttributes<T>`. Try changing the identifier to `Base<F>` and it will work fine. You're not using the generic `Base` in the extension method.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Even without `Base<T>` in the mix it doesn't work.  There _shouldn't_ be a link between `T` in `Base<T>` and the one in `WithAttributes<T>`.  I've updated the example to remove it.

Comment: Then how would you expect `Derived.WithAttributes<T>` to infer the type argument? Because `T` could be anything that inherits from `Base`, or `Base` itself, including something that isn't `Derived` or `Base`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Because it has no problem inferring it in the case of an extension method with a nearly identical signature.

Comment: @tbridge the `this` in the extension method makes the two not equivalent. In the instance method, T is any T which extends `Base`. In the extension method T is the type of the instance on which the method is invoked

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why can't the compiler infer type arguments in the first example?

Type inference uses method arguments to infer type arguments. In the first example there are no method arguments which can be used to infer type argument.

> Why does it work when called using an extension method?

Extension method is actually a static method and object which you are 'extending' is passed as an argument to extension method call:

```
Extensions.WithAttributesEx<T>(d, "one", "two")
```

As stated above, type inference uses method arguments to find type arguments. Here type argument can be inferred from the type of first method argument, which is `Derived`.

> Is there any way to make it work as an instance method on the base
>   class without explicitly specifying type argument?

Make base class generic and parametrize it with derived class (that is called [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://zpbappi.com/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-csharp/)):

```
public class Base<T>
    where T : Base<T>
{
    private List<string> attributes = new List<string>();

    public T WithAttributes(params string[] attributes)            
    {
        this.attributes.AddRange(attributes);
        return this as T;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
}
```

Usage:

```
Derived d = new Derived().WithAttributes("one", "two").WithAttributes("three");
```

Comment: Note that this will make it hard to keep, for example, a list of a variety of Derived objects that all implement Base<T> with different T's. So if you have DerivedA and DerivedB, then it's harder to store a List<Base> that keeps both DerivedA and DerivedB elements. This is something you have to design against since even with a Base that Base<T> subclasses (that lacks the T returning method), there's no way to call the method without first casting.

Comment: @MikeRoibu well, you can implement some IBase interface in base class. Then you still will have nice fluent api for building derived objects, and you will be able to process list of IBase types

Comment: nah, that can't work. The interface doesn't know what a T is, so you can't define WithAttributes in the interface. So you can have a List<IBase> list, but then you can't call list[0].WithAttributes() because you don't know what it should return. You'll have to call ((Base<DerivedA>)list[0]).WithAttributes(), and if list[1] is different, then ((Base<DerivedB>)list[1]).WithAttributes(), see what I mean?

Comment: @MikeRoibu I never suggested to define `WithAttributes` in interface

Comment: In which case you'll have to cast after pulling it from the list, before being able to call the method you're applying this pattern for. It's a downside of the pattern that I feel should be mentioned, since it does come up quite often.

Comment: @MikeRoibu I suggested keeping `T WithAttributes` for *building* derived objects. After they are properly initialized you can put derived objects into the list and use common functionality which is defined by `IBase` interface.

Comment: That's besides the point. I'm saying 'if you have a list of DerivedA and DerivedB all stored as IBase, you won't be able to go through that list and call .WithAttributes on them', which you have to understand that it could very easily happen. And even if they're not stored as IBase, there's no alternative to store them and also be able to call .WithAttributes. It's just a consequence of the pattern.

Comment: @MikeRoibu Sure but you wouldn't be able to do that anyway even if you didn't use the pattern because the only alternative is to put a copy of the method into each derived type, so you're not missing out on anything using this pattern.